# What's Triggering IE9 Compatibility Mode?

Tags: internet-explorer-9, compatibility

I can't figure out what's triggering the IE9 compatibility mode on this website, can anyone make suggestions as to what causes this? It's absolutely fine in Chrome, Safari or Firefox.

I've looked at the errors on console, deleting the body 'initialize' does not affect this.

Website is http://www.catpr.com

Many thanks for any of your suggestions.

Comment: I can't know for sure, but it could be the lack of a proper doctype declaration.

Comment: Getting couple of Access Denied exceptions. Are you debugging it on local machine?

Comment: Why do you have a script tag before your head tag?

Comment: Also in same script tag you are doing some thing with localhost??? Secondly <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">, [This option is generally intended for testing purposes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533876(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: No, trying to debug on the live version, although I have a local copy.

Comment: Tried switching out all of the above, still no luck at the moment.

Comment: Just to check have you mark this site as Intranet Site in your browser? It's not changing on my machine.

Comment: What do you mean by 'not changing' - as in - not switching to compatibility mode? Or you can't see any changes in my code? If the latter, I am making changes, testing, and then reverting if it makes no difference.

Comment: It seems to be magically working now - think it was Bolt's suggestion that fixed it. Bolt, can you post as the solution and I'll mark it up? Thanks

Comment: The compatibility mode, it's not switching to compatibility mode. Also confirm if the site is there inside the list intranet sites (inside IE options->security).